# a way to merg two mysql query into one query

Tags: mysql

is there a way to merge these two mysql command just to get one mysql command?

here is my first sql

```
select cnt1, cnt2

from (select sum(cnt) as cnt1           
  from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v  
 ) h cross join
 (select sum(cnt) as cnt2           
  from xx_dept_emp_cnt_v          
  where org_cb_id in (select cb_id from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v) 
 ) d
```

results

```
cnt1     cnt2
-----    ----
67       62
```

second mysql command

```
select     s.name software_name,
          count(s.name) install_qty

from  (select name,version,hardware_id 
   from softwares 
   group by name,version,hardware_id) s ,
   dico_soft ds

where  s.name = ds.extracted 
        and ds.formatted ='OS'
group by s.name
```

result is

```
software_name          install_qty
------------           -------------
Microsoft Window 7      1
Microsoft Window 8      42
Microsoft Window 8.1    2
```

and I'm trying to get

```
software_name           cnt1   cnt2       install_qty
------------            -----  -----      -------------
Microsoft Window 7      67     62          1
Microsoft Window 8      67     62          42
Microsoft Window 8.1    67     62          2
```

Comment: try `union all` between these two queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select cnt1, cnt2

from (select sum(cnt) as cnt1           
  from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v  
 ) h cross join
 (select sum(cnt) as cnt2           
  from xx_dept_emp_cnt_v          
  where org_cb_id in (select cb_id from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v) 
 ) d 
union
select     s.name software_name,
          count(s.name) install_qty

from  (select name,version,hardware_id 
   from softwares 
   group by name,version,hardware_id) s ,
   dico_soft ds

where  s.name = ds.extracted 
        and ds.formatted ='OS'
group by s.name
```

If you want the duplicate values than use union all.

Comment: this will give me two column cnt1 and cnt2, what I need is the column from the first sql command, added to the columns of the second sql command